# Can I use Shortcuts to tell me when to leave for a specific appointment based on Map data?

Tags: ipad, shortcut, ipados, shortcuts-app, maps

I was wondering if anyone knew of an existing Shortcut where I can get the Time that I need to leave My Current location in order to arrive at a specified address at a specified time. So lets say I have a doctors appointment at 6:00 is there a shortcut where I can input the time I need to arrive and the address of my appointment and and the output be the suggested time that I leave from my current location.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Set up the appointment in Calendar including the actual location as found in maps/

You can then set 2 alerts, one value is Time to leave.

I think the default for the second alert is Time to leave